# String in negative look ahead being partially captured

Tags: javascript, regex

My regular expression:

```
/(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99})!/g
```

My test string:

```
foo,#REF!,bar!,baz,qux!
```

It currently [matches `REF!`](https://regex101.com/r/gaDd9t/1) but the desired outcome is for only `bar!` and `qux!` to be matched. I used the negative look-ahead `(?!#REF!)` to prevent that but `REF!` is being captured as is matches `[^!,]{1,99}`.

How can prevent `REF!` getting matched - is using a negative look-ahead the correct approach?

Comment: Make sure you start matching from the start of the string or a comma, [`(?:^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99})!`](https://regex101.com/r/gaDd9t/2), your value is in Group 1. BTW, your pattern has only 1 capturing group in it.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - that works but it also matches the leading comma e.g. I get `,bar!` and `,qux!`.

Comment: Yes, but it does not capture it. As I wrote, your value is in Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - sure got it now.

Comment: A non-regex way is [also possible](https://jsfiddle.net/kjckxfax/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: shouldn't your regex actually be `(?:^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99}!)`? otherwise the backreference will not take into account the last `!` as it will not be captured

Comment: @Allan There is no backreference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your string is a comma separated item list, you may split the string with a comma, remove all empty items (if any), get only those ending with a `!` and then remove the `!` from the end of the strings:

```js
var s = "foo,#REF!,bar!,baz,qux!";
console.log(s.split(',')
 .filter(Boolean)     // remove empty items
 .filter(function (x) {return x.charAt(x.length-1)==="!" && x!== "#REF!";} ) // ends with ! and not #REF!
  .map(function(y) {return y.substr(0, y.length-1)}) // remove !
);
```

If for some reason you still need  to use a regex, you may use

```
/(?:^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99})!/g
```

Access Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaDd9t/2) here.

NOTE: You only have 1 capturing group here, as `(?!...)` is a *lookahead* that is a special regex construct. `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing* group, its value is not stored in any additional memory buffer as compared to a capturing group.

**Details**

- `(?:^|,)` - either start of string or `,`
- `(?!#REF!)` - no `#REF!` is allowed to appear right after the current location
- `([^!,]{1,99})` - Capturing group 1: 1 to 99 chars other than `!` and `,`
- `!` - a `!` char

```js
var s = "foo,#REF!,bar!,baz,qux!";
var rx = /(?:^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99})!/g, m, res=[];
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
   res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99})!
```

**Explanations:**

Adding `(?<=^|,)` forces the start of your regex matching to either the beginning of the line or to the previous comma. If you don't add it `REF!` will also be matched. The `,` will not be part of the result because it is in a lookbehind clause.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/udoxow/1/)

If you can not use lookbehind, then you can go for a solution like the one proposed by [WiktorStribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

```
(?:^|,)(?!#REF!)([^!,]{1,99}!)
```

and by referencing to the `1st` capturing group

Comment: Note that support for lookbehinds in JavaScript regex is a very recent development. This won’t work in any version of Firefox that currently exists, for example.

Comment: @Ry︁: You are completely right, I have edited my answer  accordingly! Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Thanks - I am going with Wiktor's but upvoted anyway